# Django won't connect to Docker PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, psycopg2

Created Dockerized PostgreSQL with the following settings:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

This is my `settings.py` file:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "postgres",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "postgres",
        "HOST": "db",
        "PORT": "5432",
    }
}
```

Initialized the container with `docker-compose up`, image is created and following logs are printed out:

> db_1  | 2022-06-01 11:45:10.788 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4
> address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
>
> db_1  | 2022-06-01 11:45:10.788 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6
> address "::", port 5432
>
> db_1  | 2022-06-01 11:45:10.791 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket
> "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
>
> db_1  | 2022-06-01 11:45:10.795 UTC [60] LOG:  database system was
> shut down at 2022-06-01 11:45:10 UTC
>
> db_1  | 2022-06-01 11:45:10.799 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready
> to accept connections

However, when I try to load my data fixtures to Docker Postre image with `migrate` & `loaddata` commands, the following error occurs:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Unknown host
```

I am able to connect my local PostgreSQL where I previously hosted the app, but Django won't see Docker container for some reason.

My system:

- Python 3.9.0, Django 3.2.8, psycopg2-binary 2.9.2

Any help??

Comment: `HOST` should be a hostname or a server address, did you mean `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: No, when I write localhost or 127.0.0.1, Django connects to my local Postgre.

Comment: How is django being run here? Is it in a container as well? If so, is it part of the compose? If django is ran on your host machine and not on a container, using localhost 5432 should be connecting to your db container since the host port is mapped to the container port.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `db` host isn't on the network. You could confirm that by simplying pinging db in the shell inside your django container.

Try adding a network to your docker-compose settings:

```
networks:
  develop-net:
    driver: bridge
```

That tells docker to use the bridge driver to create a network bridge between your containers. Then, in each of your containers, specify that they're on that network:

```
    networks:
      - develop-net
```

Comment: Added to docker-compose, but not sure how to add to the container.

Comment: The `networks:` directive adds that container to the network you created.